# In a flat spacetime region, is any timelike worldline segment guaranteed geodesic if it belongs to at least three distinct photon 2-surfaces?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, geodesics, foundations

Photon surfaces have been recognized as intuitive and significant concept in the description of spacetimes.
All photon 2-surfaces in flat spacetime can be concisely classified
(cmp. *"Inertial forces and photon surfaces in arbitrary spacetimes"*, [[gr-qc:0306042]](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0306042), sec. 5.1) as

- either planes, with timelike and spacelike extension,
- or rotational hyperboloids with timelike axis in the center.

I like to check an intuition about how those types of photon 2-surfaces intersect.

**My question -- Is the following statement correct?:**

If, in a flat spacetime region, a timelike worldline segment belongs to at least three distinct photon 2-surfaces,
then it is a geodesic segment, and the corresponding intersecting photon 2-surfaces are all planes.