# Partitioning flat spacetime into timelike geodesics, where any two define a photon plane, are they a shear-, expansion- and vorticity-free congruence?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, geodesics, foundations

3+1 dimensional flat spacetime, as a set of events (with certain geometric properties), can be [partitioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) in various ways into (necessarily non-intersecting) timelike geodesic worldlines.

Some, but not all, of the resulting partitionings correspond to the set of worldlines which are traced by the members of an inertial frame (in the sense of W. Rindler, i.e. ["*simply an infinite set of point particles sitting still in space relative to each other*"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics)); and those sets of worldlines are (special cases of) timelike geodesic [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)) which are moreover [characterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)#Kinematical_description) as "expansion-less", "shear-free", and "vorticity-free". (These congruences may correspondingly be a.k.a. "inertial congruences".)

Further, such expansion-less, shear-free, vorticity-free, and (as initially specified) timelike geodesic congruences in 3+1 dimensional flat spacetime have the following properties (as is readily shown by expressing the relevant geometric relations in terms of values of spacetime intervals, $s^2$, which are presumed given in the flat spacetime under consideration):

- each worldline of such a congruence is a subset of many distinct photon planes (cmp. [[gr-qc:0306042], sec. 5.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0306042)),
- any two worldlines of such a congruence are both subsets of the same (one, and only one) particular photon plane (which is thereby identified, or in other words: defined),
- if any third worldline of such a congruence has (at least) one event in common with the particular photon plane which is defined by two others, then it has all its events in common with this photon plane; thus all three worldlines are subsets of the same photon plane, and the relation of these worldlines being pairwise subsets of the same photon plane is [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

Now, I'd like to know whether a suitably inverse statement holds as well; namely

**My question:**

If 3+1 dimensional flat spacetime is partitioned into (necessarily non-intersecting) timelike geodesic worldlines such that any two of them are both subsets of the same unique photon plane, and if this subset relation is transitive, then:

Does each such set of worldlines constitute a expansion-less, shear-free, and vorticity-free timelike geodesic congruence (or for short: an inertial congruence) ?

---

Note on a generalization:

As far as the conjecture is correct (cmp. [this recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783397/12262)), that, in 3+1 dimensional flat spacetime, any timelike worldline which is subset of several (at least 3) distinct photon 2-surfaces is necessarily geodesic, and all photon 2-surfaces which are intersecting each other in this geodesic timelike worldline are necessarily photon planes, then my question from above can be phrased correspondingly with a weaker condition (and thus with greater generality):

If 3+1 dimensional flat spacetime is partitioned into (necessarily non-intersecting) timelike worldlines such that any two of them are both subsets of the same unique photon 2-surface, and if this subset relation is transitive, then:

Does each such set of worldlines constitute a expansion-less, shear-free, and vorticity-free timelike geodesic congruence (or for short: an inertial congruence) ?