# Can not-conformally-flat spacetimes be partitioned into timelike worldlines where any two of them are subsets of at least one common photon 2-surface?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, foundations

In flat spacetime it is straightforward to find and describe various sets of timelike worldlines such that

- the worldlines belonging to any one such set $\mathcal P$ [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) the spacetime,
- any two worldlines ${\mathcal A, B} \in \mathcal P$ are both together subsets of (exactly) one common photon 2-surface, ${\mathcal A, B} \subset \mathcal S$, and
- being subsets of the same, common photon 2-surface is a transitive relation of those worldlines, i.e.
  $$ ({\mathcal A, B, C} \in \mathcal P \text{ and } {\mathcal A, B} \subset \mathcal S \text{ and } {\mathcal A, C} \subset \mathcal S) \implies {\mathcal B, C} \subset \mathcal S. $$

(Partitionings of flat spacetime with those properties presumably have certain "additional properties" as well; cmp. [this recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783770/12262).)

Both, the notion of a spacetime being partitioned into a set of timelike worldlines, as well as the notion of a photon 2-surface (cmp. [[gr-qc:0306042]](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0306042)), can surely be expressed entirely in terms of [causal relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Causal_relations) between events. Consequently, for any [conformally flat spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry#Conformal_manifolds) there exist partitionings into timelike worldlines with exactly the properties listed above (but possibly with different "additional properties").

But I wonder whether this applies ("more, or less") to any, or all, other spacetimes as well. Therefore ...

**My question:**

Which not-conformally-flat spacetimes can be partitioned into timelike worldlines, such that any two of those worldlines are subsets of (at least) one common photon 2-surface ?